# Problem conditions to use Laplacian solvers

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, linear-algebra, matrices, sparse-matrix

I am trying to use Laplacian Solvers to solve a linear equation. I am just learning it (form [here](https://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/vishnoi/Lxb-Web.pdf)), so my question is very basic and it might not even make sense.

Suppose that we want to solve Ax=b, where matrix A is not a Laplacian matrix. Under what condition on A and b, we can solve Ax=b using Laplacian solvers?

P.S. Introducing a good reference will be helpful too.

Comment: Please don't simultaneously cross-post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good question. You can use a Laplacian solver if $A$ is symmetric and diagonally semi-dominant (SDD). This is the subject of Theorem 9.2 in your reference book from Vishnoi. A good exposition of the proof (which was originally by Gremban) can be found in Appendix A of the paper by Kelner, Orecchia, Sidford and Zhu ([arXiv:1301.6628](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6628)).

A recent result by Kyng and Zhang ([arXiv:1705.02944](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02944)) suggests that current Laplacian solvers are probably restricted to this class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer and the references are really helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately the matrix $A$ in my equation is not SDD, but it is sparse. Is there any other approach that I can use to solve it fast?

Comment: For general sparse matrices you can do slightly better. See e.g. [arXiv:2007.10254](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.10254) and references therein.

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for.